# Ajax doesn't post data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

[SOLVED]

That was THE most difficult bug ever - all due to copy/paste stuff up.

This:

```
$('#errors'+bUID).append('<ul id="error_list"'+bUID+'></ul>');
```

should have been that:

```
$('#errors'+bUID).append('<ul id="error_list'+bUID+'"></ul>');
```

The damn '+bUID+' was pasted AFTER the " , not BEFORE!

Of course it couldn't append anything to it... 2 weeks...2 WEEKS wasted!!! )))

---

Here's the js:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    bUID = $(this).find('input[name=bUID]').data("buid");
    e.preventDefault();
    submitForm(bUID);
    alert(bUID);
});

function submitForm(bUID) {
    var name = $('#name'+bUID).val();
    var email = $('#email'+bUID).val();
    var message = $('#message'+bUID).val();
    var code = $('#code'+bUID).val();
    alert(bUID);

    // also tried this
    var post_data = {
    'name': $('#name'+bUID).val(),
    'email': $('#email'+bUID).val(),
    'message': $('#message'+bUID).val(),
    'code': $('#code'+bUID).val(),
    'buid': bUID,
    };
    alert(Object.keys(post_data).length);


    // ALSO tried this instead of ajax:
    //$.post($('#contact_form'+bUID).attr('action'), post_data, function(response){
    alert(response);
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "post",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message + "&code=" + code + "&buid=" + bUID,
        //data: post_data,
        url:   $('#contact_form'+bUID).attr('action'),
        success: function(response) {
            if (typeof response !== 'undefined' && response.length > 0) {
                if (response[0] == "success") {
                    $('#success'+bUID).append('<p>Success</p>');
                }
                else {
                    $('#errors'+bUID).append('<p>' + js_errors + '</p>');
                    $('#errors'+bUID).append('<ul id="error_list"'+bUID+'></ul>');
                    $.each(response, function(i, v){
                        if (i > 0) {
                            $('#error_list'+bUID).append('<li>' + v + '</li>');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

here's the action in view.php:

```
<?php
$bUID = $controller->getBlockUID($b);
$form = Loader::helper('form');
$formAction = $view->action('submit', Core::make('token')->generate('contact_form'.$bUID));
?>

<form id="contact_form<?php echo $bUID; ?>" 
    class="contact-form" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data" 
    action="<?php echo $formAction?>" 
    method="post" 
    accept-charset="utf-8">

    <?php echo $bUID; ?><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="bUID" data-buid="<?php echo $bUID; ?>" data-popup="<?php echo $popup; ?>">

   ...etc.
```

and here's the controller.php:

```
public function action_submit($token = false, $bID = false) 
{
    $this->form_errors = array();
    array_push($this->form_errors, "error");
    array_push($this->form_errors, $_POST['name']);
    array_push($this->form_errors, $_POST['email']);
    array_push($this->form_errors, $_POST['message']);
    array_push($this->form_errors, $_POST['code']);
    array_push($this->form_errors, $_POST['buid']);
    echo Core::make('helper/json')->encode($this->form_errors, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    exit;
}
```

it gets all data and shows it in alert but then trows the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in ["error","gggg","gggg@gmail.commm","gggggggggggggggggggggggg","gggg","171"]
    at r (jquery.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.success (view.js:132)
    at j (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at x (jquery.js:5)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.js:5)
```

Line 132 of the js file is this: $.each(response, function(i, v){

I can't figure out what's wrong. The alert works and returns entered data: "error,gggg,gggg@gmail.commm,gggggggggggggggggggggg,gggg,171‌", but php retruns null objects: "["error",null,null,null,null,null]" - $_POST is empty!

What's wrong here? Why doesn't the form get posted?

Thank you very much.

Comment: yes, all values inside submitForm take values from the form, I checked

Comment: Did you inspect your browser's console (If your'e using Chrome, go to Network and check **Preserve Log**) to verify if the data are being sent correctly?

Comment: O-oh! Ctrl-F5 and now I have this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in gggg, this points to this line in js: $.each(response, function(i, v){ - what's wrong here? 'gggg' is what's entered in the form field

Comment: Your'e **response** variable is an array?

Comment: yes, it's an array

Comment: Can you check using .lenght? If is, post the rest of the code please!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160419/discussion-between-linuxoid-and-jnewbie).

Comment: apparently that's not an array, but objects, that's why it doesn't have length. alert(Object.keys(post_data).length); returns 5 - so it's fine. the issue is just right after it. either the array doesn't get passed to php, or an empty array is passed, or php can't read it and has nulls

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `return false;` to prevent your form from submitting to its desired action?

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    bUID = $(this).find('input[name=bUID]').data("buid");
    //e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropagation();
    submitForm(bUID);
    alert(bUID);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes. It does the same thing as the e.preventDefault();. But null is returned. that is the $_POST[] has nothing.

Comment: Your post was edited since I made my answer. It wasn't originally there/uncommented. Have you tried posting the data as an object? `data:
 {name: name, email: email}` etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
function submitForm(bUID) {
    var name = $('#name'+bUID).val();
    var email = $('#email'+bUID).val();
    var message = $('#message'+bUID).val();
    var code = $('#code'+bUID).val();

    $.post($('#contact_form'+bUID).attr('action'), {name:name, email:email, message:message, code:code, buid:bUID}, function(result){
        alert(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works. $.post($('#contact_form'+bUID).attr('action'), post_data, function(result){ works too

Comment: how come the post works but ajax doesn't? is there any difference between the 2? Preference?

Comment: I tried with the rest of the post processing and it still throws an error at $.each(response, function(i, v){ - see the post above (updated)

Answer (score 0):

Your `post_data` variable was correct. As it is now your `data` attribute in your ajax is wrong - it's in `GET` format (a string), not `POST`. The correct way (json) is;

```
$.ajax({
   dataType: "json",
   type: "post",
   data: {
       name: nameVar,
       email: emailVar,
       message: messageVar
   },
   url: ...,
   success: function(data) {
       ...
   }
});
```

I "renamed" your variables to try and avoid variables with the same names as keys (e.g. you want to post "name", setting a variable "name" might conflict).

Comment: well, it still returns nothing, although the alert shows all data as entered.

Comment: Try and remove all unnessecary code. Comment out everything in "success", and put a simple `alert("Success");`. Make sure to have an `error` callback function too, so you know if it fails.

Comment: yes, alert works: "error,gggg,gggg@gmail.commm,gggggggggggggggggggggg,gggg,171"

Comment: Try submit the without ajax to see if the PHP file has any errors

Comment: I'm sure the error is here: $.each(response, function(i, v){

Comment: php says: "["error",null,null,null,null,null]" - $_POST is empty!

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
    data: form.serializeArray()
```

Like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'url to post data',
dataType: "json",
method: "post",
data: form.serializeArray(),
 success: function(data) {
   // another staff here, you can write console.log(data) to see what server responded
 },
 fail: function(data) {
     console.log(data) // if any error happens it will show in browsers console
  }
});
```

**Another tips: in server side you can use http_response_code(200) for success, http_response_code(400) for errors, http_response_code(403) if authorisation is required**

Comment: which form will that be? I have multiple forms on page

Comment: I don’t know my friend. You can manage it by writing var form = $(‘#formid’);